# Swift error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

```
func fontForDisplay(atIndexPath indexPath : NSIndexPath) -> UIFont? {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let familyName = familyNames[indexPath.row]
        let fontName = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName).first as String!
        return UIFont(name: fontName, size: cellPointSize)
    }else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Error Message : FontName is nil
But I don't know how to solve it

I need help.  Thanks

Comment: check your familyNames array, i guess familyName is nil too

Comment: Please show what are the contents have this familyNames array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
func fontForDisplay(atIndexPath indexPath : NSIndexPath) -> UIFont? {
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    let familyName = familyNames[indexPath.row]
    if let fontName = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName).first as String! {

        return UIFont(name: fontName, size: cellPointSize)
    } else {
       return nil
    }

    }else {
        return nil
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention :）

Answer (score 1):

You can use guard. It allows you to focus on valid statements and to use optional binding for fontName :

```
func fontForDisplay(atIndexPath indexPath : NSIndexPath) -> UIFont? {
    guard indexPath.section == 0 else { return nil }
    let familyName = familyNames[indexPath.row]
    guard let fontName = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName).first else { return nil }
    return UIFont(name: fontName, size: cellPointSize)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When i got this error it was because there is an IBObject that has not been called into the coreesponding viewcontroller .swift.

i would suggest you ctrl-click on all objects and should bring up a black menu, with all objext association in, sometime you can have 2 object calls to the .swift file on the same  IBObject, and although you have deleted it in the code, it still thinks that it is there in the storyboard!

i hope that this helps

Comment: Thank you for your attention :）